# Confused by the operator definitions of Int in Scala

Tags: scala

The scala tutorial says that `Int`'s add operation is actually a method call: `1+1` means `1.+(1)`

But when I look into the source code of `Int.scala`, it appears that the method will simply print an error message. Could anyone explain to me how this works?

```
 def +(x: Int): Int = sys.error("stub")
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Int is a [value class](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/128), which is somewhat different than other classes.  There is no way to express primitive addition in scala without getting into a recursive definition.  For example if the definition of + was,

```
def +(x: Int): Int = this + x
```

Then calling + would invoke + which would invoke + which ...

Scala needs to compile the methods on value classes into the java byte codes for addition/subtraction/etc.

The compiler does compile + into the java bytecode for addition, but the scala library authors wrote Int.scala with stub methods to make it a valid scala source file.  Those stub methods are never actually invoked.

Answer (score 7):

As the implementation says, that method is a stub. Apparently its implementation is provided by the Scala compiler when the code is compiled, because `int + int` is a primitive operation and the Scala language does not itself have primitives - only the compiler knows about primitives on the JVM.

Answer (score 7):

It is important to realize that operators are methods as a matter of how one interacts with the language. Things like `+` on `Int` act like any other method in Scala, instead of being something that plays by their own rules.

However, at the *implementation level*, they are not methods at all: to the JVM only classes have methods, and the `AnyVal` subclasses are not classes as far as the JVM is concerned. Unsurprisingly, at the implementation level they act mostly like Java primitives.